# Center element with left aligned element inline within container

Tags: css, html, alignment, positioning

I have two `<div>` elements inside a container `<div>` and I need to align one of them on the left of the container, and the other in the center of the container while keeping them inline.

If I just `float` the first one left, the second one gets pushed off-center to the right.

Right now my best solution is to make the container `position: relative` with `text-align: center` and align the first element to left with `position: absolute`.

Perhaps there is an alternative, better way to do this, without going for absolute positions?

Comment: are the widths of these elements static?

Comment: no, should've mentioned that, sorry.

Comment: I'm late to the party but I find your approach better than the accepted answer - `style="position: absolute; left: 0"` on the `div` you want to left align.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a really long shot, but i've found that applying a big negative margin-right on the left floated element will compensate on the center-offset...

try giving the floated div a `margin-right: -1000px;`

Comment: not entirely sure how this fares in all browsers, it works for me on the latest chrome.

Comment: although it looks like a sketchy solution and I have no idea how and why, it does seem to work in chrome and safari for me. Thanks! I wonder how IE sees it tho..

Comment: Can you count on an unexplainable behavior of the browser? Chrome and Safari both based on WebKit - that's why the both behave the same way. Check in Opera and Firefox. If it works there - don't bother checking IE. Most likely, IE won't accept that.

Comment: lol, exactly, this is very sketchy, and i have very limited understanding of why this actually works. i normally don't post such loosely knit solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a restriction for two div in a div? You could make 4 `divs`:

```
<div id="one">
    <div id="first"></div>
    <div id="two">
        <div id="second"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And apply `float: left` to `#first` and `#two` and then `margin: auto` the `#second`